# How to test a function with a promise returned using jest?

Tags: javascript, jestjs, es6-promise

Here is my function

```
const FS = require('fs');
const PARSER = new $RefParser;

const dereference = (filePath)=>{
  let parsedJSON = PARSER.dereference(filePath,{dereference: {circular: false}});

  return parsedJSON.then(result =>{
    const dereferencedJSON = JSON.stringify(result,null,2);
    FS.writeFileSync(filePath,dereferencedJSON);
  }).catch((error)=>{
      console.log(error.message);
  });
};

module.exports = {
  dereferenceSchema,
  PARSER
};
```

here is the test

```
const {dereferenceSchema,PARSER} = require('../../src/dereferenceService');

describe('derefrencing service test',() =>{
    it('Should throw ReferenceError if circular reference detected',  done => {
        beforeEach(()=>{
            PARSER.dereference = jest.fn();
       });
        dereferenceSchema(CIRCULAR_REF_FILE).then((data) => {
            console.log(data) // this gives me undefined
            done();
        })
        
    });
});
```

I also tried

```
describe('derefrencing service test',() =>{

    it('Should throw ReferenceError if circular reference detected',  async () => {
        expect.assertions(1);
        return dereferenceSchema(CIRCULAR_REF_FILE).catch((e)=>{
            expect(e).toEqual('ReferenceError');
        }
        );
    });
});
//This will have Error: Expected one assertion to be called but received zero assertion calls.
```

The implementation of test above is always pass no matter the what condition is, however, there still has the `ReferenceError` in console, which comes from my `catch` of `derefrenceSchema` function.

I am totally new to jest and I have tried different method, either using something working with`done()` or `jest.fn()`.

I would be really appreciate it if someone can help me here.

Comment: In your most recent version with `expect.assertions(1)`, change `.catch()` to `.then()`. What happens?

Comment: It will give me undefined, if i ```console.log``` the data. @Code-Apprentice

Comment: The value doesn't really matter here. The important part is that the promise returned by `dereferenceSchema()` resolves instead of throwing an error. This means either your implementation is incorrect and you need to change it to throw an error for the situation you are testing or that you need to use `.then()` in your test instead of `.catch()`. Another possibility is that your test is incorrect and it doesn't trigger the error that you are trying to test for.

Comment: You should post your solution as an answer instead of editing your question.

Comment: This solution makes sense. Since `dereferenceSchema()` has a `.catch()` already, the resulting promise (after that `.catch()` processes) is a resolved promise, not an error.

Answer (score 2):

There are a couple of issues to resolve here. First, return the promise from your test to allow the Jest framework to process it:

```
describe('derefrencing service test',() =>{
    it('Should throw ReferenceError if circular reference detected',  done => {
        beforeEach(()=>{
            PARSER.dereference = jest.fn();
        });

        // add "return" here:
        return dereferenceSchema(CIRCULAR_REF_FILE).then(() => {
            done();
        }).catch(e => {
            expect(e.name).toMatch('ReferenceError');
            done();
        });
        
    });
});
```

Second, you don't need both a `.then()` and a `.catch()` in your test. You should be testing only a single scenario that has a known outcome. For different inputs with different results, you should write separate tests for each scenario.

Third, there is evidence from your debugging that the promise returned by `dereferenceSchema()` is resolved, but it sounds like you expect it to throw an error. This means either `dereferenceSchema()` is incorrect or the test is incorrect. If `dereferenceSchema()` is incorrect, then you need to fix it accordingly. The test could be incorrect in at least two different ways:

1. The setup is wrong and doesn't actually trigger the error you are testing for. This could be because the `beforeEach()` is in the incorrect place. It should be nested inside the `describe()`, but not in the `it()`. `beforeEach()` is run before each `it()` in a `describe()`. This is useful when you have multiple tests that require the same set up.
2. The way you expect the result is wrong. You might just need to change your test to have an expect in a `.then()` clause instead of a `.catch()` clause.

Comment: Hi @Code-Apprentice, thanks for helping here! I believe the test will still always pass even with return added. Since when I try ```expect(e.name).toMatch('abc');```, it still pass. Any comments for that?

Comment: @P.G Most likely the test is hitting the `.then()` path. I suggest you include a `expect()` in that callback.

Comment: @P.G Do you really need both a `.then()` and a `.catch()` in the same test? A test should be written so that it covers one scenario: calling function `foo()` with input `blah blah` results in `blah blah`. There might be different inputs that cause different results. Each of those scenarios should be separate tests. In this light, there should probably be either a `.then()` or a `.catch()` in a given test, but not both. Write a separate test for the error case.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning that, I have edited the code in my question. The problem right now, is it does not enter the promise. The assertion is 0, instead of 1. @Code-Apprentice

Comment: @P.G your `expect.assertions(1)` executes before the `.catch()` clause, so of course it fails.

Comment: @P.G Another oddity I just noticed is the placement of `beforeEach()`. This should go in a `describe()` block. The `beforeEach()` will be executed before each `it()` block in the `describe()`.

Comment: I am referring this [jest doc](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/tutorial-async.html#content), basically just copy paste. From my understanding, this is because the test never go into the promise, I am thinking maybe mocking promise would work here? Just not sure how to do it. Thanks. @Code-Apprentice

Comment: @P.G Mocking promise sounds hinky to me. I suggest adding `console.log()` statements to trace the execution of your test. It sounds like the `.catch()` isn't being executed which means that the promise returned from `dereferenceSchema()` resolves without any errors. I would also try changing the `.catch()` to a `.then()` with a `console.log()` call inside to see if it prints out.

Comment: @P.G My earlier comment about `expect.assertions()` seems to be incorrect. The docs you linked use it in the same way. Notice how that doc also returns the promise as I stated in my original answer. So you definitely need that fix. There appears to be more going on here, though, so you still aren't getting the expected result. As I said earlier, you need to debug more with `console.log()` or other tools.

Comment: @P.G Please edit your question instead of my answer.

Comment: @P.G I have updated my answer according to the things we have discussed.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is solved by creating the other function used to `catch` errors, deleting .catch from the `dereferenceSchema` function.

```
const catchErrorFunc = (p) =>{
  dereferenceSchema(p).catch((error)=>{
    console.log(error.name);
    return error;
  });
};
```

Comment: FYI, The reason to fix like this is the error that needed to be test is not throwed by the returned promise, It's throwed by the upper function.